# Trying to use Facebook login button and cocos2dx but facebook needs a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, widget, cocos2d-x

I was given a game to modify by adding a Facebook login.

I have a fragment ready from a previous project.

To add a facebook.widget.LoginButton to a Fragment the main activity has to extend FragmentActivity.

The game uses Cocos2dx, so my Main activity extends Cocos2dxActivity

I tried changing Cocos2dxActivty to extend FragmentActivity instead of just Activity but got about 200 errors.

Is there any way around this?

If not, please suggest a layout or widget that can go over the current screen/activity instead of a fragment

Comment: you can use custom button login

Comment: check this link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233042/how-to-login-facebook-using-sdk-4-1-0-in-android/30233276#30233276