# How to login facebook using sdk 4.1.0 in android?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

[I"m writing codes for my login Page for my application.i have already made my login successful with the given email and password but i"m facing a problem while writing the codes for login with facebook.I have already checked this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

but still i"m getting errors while running  my code as per instructions.I"m new to android developing...so any proper help would be praiseworthy.Thankx in advance.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzG3F.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here i"m providing a working solution for facebook login with sdk4.

First of all add dependency on build.gradle(Module app) under
 dependencies {......

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'` }
Then Sync Gradle....
Thereafter,in Android Manifest do the following changes:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/> //write the app_id u have generated in res/values/strings.xml folder.
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider456579934439214"
              android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
              android:exported="true" />

 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
              android:configChanges=
                  "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

After this write the following codes in ur MainActivity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //callback registration

            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            // App code

                            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
                            Log.e("-->", Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends").toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

My activity_main.xml file are as follows:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

U can customize the button as per requirement

Comment: How can I get user's name with this example?

Answer (score 5):

if you what customlogin button then

In on create meathod

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); // declare it globally "CallbackManager callbackManager "

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>(){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("LoginManager", "On Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("LoginManager", "On Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("LoginManager", "On Cancel");
        }
    });
```

On any button click call this

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email"));
```

onActivity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: resolved it for me the issue was firebase-ui-auth library.

Comment: your answer is correct my issue was totally due to another reasons.