# FacebookCallback.onCancel is getting called when trying to login using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an Android app and I am trying to use Facebook's SDK (version 4.1.0) to get a token and log in. Here is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Log.v(TAG, "Facebook login was successful");
                String authToken = accessToken.getToken();
                // User authToken here:
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.v(TAG, "Facebook login was canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Facebook login failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Button facebook_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbButton);

        facebook_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The code switched to the Facebook app and back and `OnActivityResult()` is called. However, every time the callback method that is called is `onCancel()`. Note that I am not using the `LoginButton` provided by Facebook, and I have my own button (although I tried that approach and the result was the same). I double and triple checked my *app ID* and the *keyhash* generated by the app and they look correct too. So, I don't know what else may be wrong. Any help at this point is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233042/how-to-login-facebook-using-sdk-4-1-0-in-android/30233276#30233276

Comment: Thanks for the link. I made two changes to my code. One is to use facebook sdk version 4.2.0, and the other is to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize before calling setContentView (recommended by some people in other pages). However, neither one of them helped fix the issue and onCancel() is still being called every single time.

Comment: plz install in another mobile or login with other id

Comment: Is there anything in logcat?

Comment: Good point Ming. I actually looked and I found this error message in the logcat: "com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: (#100) Param third_party_app_id must be a valid application id [extra]", which clearly states my APP ID is wrong. But I checked it 3 times (After all, how hard is it to copy and paste the APP ID from their site into Android Studio). I also checked my Keyhash again and it is also correct.

Comment: There is a change log for facebook sdk 4.1.2 in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x), stating that they fixed something about calling OnCancel by mistake. But I am using their sdk 4.2.0 now.

Answer (score 26):

yes i was facing the same issue, resolved it by using the below code just before login

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: @shahins accept this answer plz, cause it is the solution.

Answer (score 10):

The reason behind this behaviour is that you are already logged in. So when you revoke it, oncancel() gets called instead of onsubmit(). So just perform logout on your application's logout button like this

Import -->

```
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
```

Implementation -->

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: LoginManager.getInstance().logout(); is not working for me

Comment: @karthikkolanji: I have just updated the answer. there is the typo in logout.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, eventually I found the problem. The activity calling facebook login fragment had `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

```
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if (accessToken == null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login unSuccessful..Please contact developer... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login attempt failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

- List item

Answer (score 2):

@Doru's comment lead me to the solution. I used the Facebook activity rather than fragment.

Instead of

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

I needed to write

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

What's nasty about this bug, is that it only occurs on old Android versions (e.g. 4.4.2, not 5.0).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this in the future, this can also be caused by the Facebook native app installed on the device blocking login due to reason X.

In my case, this was being thrown every single time I attempted login. I finally switched over to the native Facebook app and as it opened, it required authentication and had me log in again due to some 'suspicious activity' (I think I changed my number recently).

If you are doing everything that is listed above and users are still complaining about it (and they have the app installed, you can use the code at the bottom to see if the Facebook app in installed:) you may wish to include a dialog that asks them to check the Facebook app and make sure they are still logged in, which would then prompt them to fix any errors before tabbing back into your application.

```
//Code to check if Facebook app is installed:
public static boolean doesUserHaveFacebookAppInstalled(Context context){
    try{
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0 );
        return true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply because the APP ID needed to be in double-quotes.

Comment: I have the same issue, however mine is working on one device....but not on the other one. You'r answer is not generally correct and you should unmark it as being one.